# adding library for google map api v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I cannot add google play service library project in my existing android app project to implement google map. Android dependencies are also not been added in the existing app project. It shows me error. I am always trying to add it from my saved sdk manager folder in my adt bundle but the library project is not added. Though I have imported the google_play_service_lib project in my package explorer. Please some body help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Error It shows can you explain.. It is due to not finding correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Import the android project library "google-play-services_lib" in your Eclipse workspace.

File > Import > Android > Existing Project in WorkSpace.

Select path to google play services library. Click Ok.

Go to your Project Settings (right click project).
then go to Android Tab in left.

Under library section click ADD to add the library project. Apply the settings.

Answer (score 0):

RightClick On Project->property->Android->Add->select google play services lib ->Apply->ok

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `Your Drive:\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services` add it in your eclipse, if this will added if you have completed whole process of google map.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your library and project in the same Workspace.

RightClick On Project->properties->Android->Add->select googleplayservices library->Apply->ok

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

**File>New>Project>Android>Android Project from Existing code>Browse: Navigate to adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services> Select libproject**

[image]

Then you can add this Library project in your own project.

Hope this will help.